# return type of count or max value count can return mysql

Tags: java, mysql

In small,
**What is the type for column returned by `count(*)`  sql ?**

**What is the max value that can be returned by `count(*)` column?**

Detail Explanation:
I have database with million of records and if I use `count(*)` then I am curios to know which type is returned in that columns, there are different [Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) of MySQL what type is returned in `count(*)` column, so that I know what max value can be given by that column.

I am using java program to traverse the whole database in paged way so I want to know how many records are there and if billions of records are there then will I be limited with `count` on some upper value.

Comment: count returns a bigint see **[mysql count reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the type for column returned by count(*) sql ?

It is BIGINT.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement. **The result is a BIGINT value**.

---

> What is the max value that can be returned by count(*) column?

The range of BigInt is **-9223372036854775808** to **9223372036854775807** which is sufficient enough to hold the values of your table.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to retrieve the last record from a MariaDB table using `JpaRepository` and the value returned was `BigInteger`, so had to change the return type to `BigInteger` and in the service layer we can cast it to Long using `.longValue()` if needed.

```
`@Query(value = "SELECT max(id) FROM inventory", nativeQuery = true)`
`Optional<Long> getLastFileSequenceNumber()`
```

Changed to :

```
`@Query(value = "SELECT max(id) FROM inventory", nativeQuery = true)`
`Optional<BigInteger> getLastRecord()`
```

In Service layer:

`getLastRecord().get().longValue()`